# Undefined url after trying to obtain attachment url

Tags: php, wordpress

In the backend of WordPress, I have an option where the user can add multiple images. These images will then be `explode`'d an shown within the `li`, that's the aim anyway.

But I'm receiving undefined index url on `$result .= $attachmentImage ? $attachmentImage['url'] : '';`.

**Markup**:

```
$image = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'image' => 'image',
    ), 
    $atts 
);

$image_ids = explode(',',$image['image']);

$result = "<div class='imageCarousel'>";
$result .= "<div class='imageCarousel__container justify-content-center'>";
$result .= "<ul>";

foreach( $image_ids as $image_id ){
    $result .='<li>';
    $result .= 'test'. $image_id;
    $attachmentImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' );
    $result .= $attachmentImage ? $attachmentImage['url'] : '';
    $result .='</li>';
}

$result .= "</ul>";
$result .= "</div>";
$result .= "</div>";

return $result;
```

A `var_dump($attachmentImage)` returns nothing?

Comment: `var_dump` does not ever return _“nothing”_, even trying to dump a non-existing variable would get you at least `null`. Plus, `$attachmentImage` must have a value that evaluates to true in some way, otherwise you could not get that error from `$result .= $attachmentImage ? $attachmentImage['url'] : '';` to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code, while calling the short code need to add the valid image id by comma separated.

like.

```
//image1 is name of shortcode, and 10,11,12 is valid id of image
echo do_shortcode('[image1 image=10,11,12]');
```

you are getting Receiving 'undefined index url' because wp_get_attachment_image_src return an array with the following elements.

```
[0] => url
[1] => width
[2] => height
[3] = >
```

So in code you have need to get the image url by $attachmentImage['0'].

```
//$attachmentImage['0'] - will display the url of image
$result .= $attachmentImage ? $attachmentImage['0'] : '';
```